# Turn NSMutableDictionary to NSData in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I got stuck in the following code in Swift

```
var dict:NSMutableDictionary=NSMutableDictionary()
dict.setValue("Ray", forKey: "name")
var err: NSError?
let postData:NSData! = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options:NSJSONWritingOptions.NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted, error: &err)
```

what's wrong with my code? Always compile error"'NSJSONWritingOptions.Type' does not have a member named 'NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted'".

Thank you all!

Comment: what compile error? show the full error message and indicate the line cause it

Comment: Thank you all!@BryanChen @Kreiri Still got error"'NSJSONWritingOptions.Type' does not have a member named 'NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted'"

Comment: It's `NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted`, not `NSJSONWritingOptions.NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted`. As you would know if you looked at NSJSONWritingOptions documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use,

```
var dict:NSMutableDictionary=NSMutableDictionary()
dict.setValue("Ray", forKey: "name")
var err: NSError?
let postData:NSData! = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, 
                       options:NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &err)
```

This works perfect for me.

In swift You can directly user enum values with "." without **full EnumName**.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var dict : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    dict.setValue("Ray", forKey: "name")
    var err: NSError?
    let postData:NSData? = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict,options:.PrettyPrinted, error: &err)
    if(postData)
    {
      println(postData!.description)
    }
```